# Pass variable from beforeLaunch to onPrepare

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver, protractor, jasmine2.0

I'm using Protractor with `sharedTestFiles: true` in the config, I need to create a common folder for all the reports that will be run for all suites.

Was trying to achieve this by defining a `date` variable inside `beforeLaunch` and then passing this to the `onPrepare` function but it's returning as `undefined`.

I'm trying to wait for the `date` variable to get defined (thought it could be an async issue), but even after 10 sec of waiting, date is still not defined. Is this even possible, can one pass a variable from `beforeLaunch` to `onPrepare`?

```
beforeLaunch: function() {
   date = dateTime.getFullDateTime();
}

onPrepare: function() {
   return webdriver.promise.delayed(1000).then(function() {
      return browser.driver.wait(function() {
         if(date !== undefined) { return true; }
      }
   }, 10000, 'onPrepare wait');
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. If you want a common folder then define a variable with the path of common folder in your onPrepare function. Then provide the common path to the reporter that you are using. Thanks